# dial movement for compass in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, xcode4, compass-geolocation

I got a magnetic heading value from a compass. Now I need to rotate the needle based on the heading(angle) from that. Please someone guide me how to do this.

Thanks Prior...

Answer (score 2):

You can always transform (rotate) your layer (compass) with CGAffineTransformMakeRotation. For further reference take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550179/how-to-transform-rotate-a-already-exist-calayer-animation).